# Adding a input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a `field2Label` after `field1Label`, `field2Input` after `field1Input` and `field2Label` and `field2Input` before my submit button using jQuery.

So it looks something like this.

Desired output.

[image]

But my `field2Label` and `field2Input` doesn't show up. Please help.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var formGroupRowDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",
   'form-group row');
 var emptyColumn = $(document.createElement('div'))
   .attr("class", 'col-md-2');

 var emptyColumn2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",
   'col-md-2');

 var field2Label = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",
   'col-md-2');

 var field2Input = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",
   'col-md-3');

 emptyColumn.appendTo(formGroupRowDiv);
 emptyColumn2.appendTo(formGroupRowDiv);

 field2Label.appendTo(formGroupRowDiv);
 field2Label.insertAfter('#field1Label').html(
   '<label for="field2Label">Field 2</label>');

 field2Input
   .appendTo(formGroupRowDiv)
   .insertAfter('#field1Input')
   .html(
     '<input id="field2Input"'
    + '" name="field2Input"'
    + '" type="text" class="form-control">');
 formGroupRowDiv.appendTo(".container");
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form id="form" name="form" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <label id="field1Label" for="field1">Field 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1Input"
      name="field1Input" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
     <button id="newFieldBtn" value="newField" type="submit"
      name="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use pure javascript while you include jquery?

Comment: `$(document.createElement('div'))` == `$('<div>')`!

Comment: You forgot to wrap your code in a DOM ready handler and it precedes the HTML it refers to. Do'h!

Comment: Also, please use `addClass()` and not `attr('class'`...

Comment: well i thought javascript and jquery could be combined...

Comment: They can be combined, but when in jQuery... use jQuery (much shorter - as you can see by the first answer below) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in JQuery in simple 2 lines. Since you know what markup you require, create a markup string and append it after the first element in the form.

The key is to execute this script after just before the end of body tag.

```
   var formGroupRowDiv = '<div class="form-group row"> <div class="col-md-2"></div> <div class="col-md-2"></div> <div class="col-md-2"> <label id="field1Label" for="field1">Field 2</label> </div> <div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2Input" name="field2Input" /> </div> </div>';
   $("#form > :first").after(formGroupRowDiv);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form id="form" name="form" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <label id="field1Label" for="field1">Field 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1Input"
      name="field1Input" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
     <button id="newFieldBtn" value="newField" type="submit"
      name="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
 
    var formGroupRowDiv = '<div class="form-group row"> <div class="col-md-2"></div> <div class="col-md-2"></div> <div class="col-md-2"> <label id="field1Label" for="field1">Field 2</label> </div> <div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2Input" name="field2Input" /> </div> </div>';
   $("#form > :first").after(formGroupRowDiv);
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$($("#form").children()[0])` is overkill. That should be just `$("#form").children().first()` or `$("#form > :first")`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xqj6s9z/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // firstRow is a row that you want to clone
    var firstRow = $("#form").find(".row").eq(0);

    // el is a cloned element, full copy of firstRow
    var el = firstRow.clone();

    // find <input> among el descendants and set proper attributes
    el.find("input").attr("name", "new_name").attr("id", "newId");

    // find <label> among el descendants and set proper attributes
    el.find("label").attr("id","newId").text("label2");

    // add `el` (cloned element) after `firstRow`
    firstRow.after(el);
});
```